# How to filter Google Places Autocomplete Results by my current location? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, search, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am currently follow what they do in the developer guide for adding a full screen controller in swift. However when I search it just shows me general results and not specific to my general area. Is there anyway to alter this code to have bounds within my current location:

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(String(describing: place.formattedAddress))")
    print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 17)
    mainMap?.animate(to: camera)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    viewController.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Comment: There doesn't look to be a way to filter to your specific location, bounds, etc. from the widget. The only option I've figured is having to creating your own lookup using the url. Here is a link (https://techstricks.com/custom-google-place-autocomplete-android/) for android that can be translated to swift that may help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply autocomplete filter

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.country = Locale.current.regionCode
resultsViewController?.autocompleteFilter = filter
```

> /**  * The country to restrict results to. This should be a ISO 3166-1
>   Alpha-2 country code (case  * insensitive). If nil, no country
>   filtering will take place.  */